# unable to pass data to a different class

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

My main class `MainScreenState` has a function `saveRideRequest` that saves a node to firebase where I need to get a key from, I need to pass this key to another class `TipTop` but every time my code runs the value sent and obtained is null. How can I fix it ? In short, I want to pass `rideRequestRef.key` from `mainScreen` to class `TipTop` as `rideReqKey`

```
class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  DatabaseReference rideRequestRef;
  void saveRideRequest()  {
    rideRequestRef =
        FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Ride Requests").push();

    ///some code
    print (rideRequestRef.key); //gets correct value
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(child: TipTop(
        saveRiderAndSearchNearRidecallback: (rideReqKey, listDriver) async {
      saveRideRequest();
      rideReqKey = rideRequestRef.key;
    }));
  }
}

class TipTop extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(String, List) saveRiderAndSearchNearRidecallback;
  const TipTop({Key key, this.saveRiderAndSearchNearRidecallback})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _StateTipTop();
}

class _StateTipTop extends State<TipTop> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(child: GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        String rideReqKey;
        List tempList;
        widget.saveRiderAndSearchNearRidecallback(rideReqKey, tempList);
        print(rideReqKey); //Null here
      },
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  DatabaseReference rideRequestRef;
  void saveRideRequest()  {
    rideRequestRef =
        FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Ride Requests").push();

    ///some code
    print (rideRequestRef.key); //gets correct value
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(child: TipTop(
        saveRiderAndSearchNearRidecallback: (rideReqKey, listDriver) async {
      saveRideRequest();
      rideReqKey = rideRequestRef.key;
    },
 rideReqKey:rideRequestRef.key
));
  }
}
```

```
class TipTop extends StatefulWidget {
  final String rideReqKey;
  final Function(String, List) saveRiderAndSearchNearRidecallback;
  const TipTop({Key key, this.saveRiderAndSearchNearRidecallback, this. rideReqKey})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _StateTipTop();
}

class _StateTipTop extends State<TipTop> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(child: GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        List tempList;
        widget.saveRiderAndSearchNearRidecallback(rideReqKey, tempList);
        print(rideReqKey); //No longer null.
      },
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but its not working,  now the `rideReqKey` under `widget.saveRiderAndSearchNearRidecallback(rideReqKey, tempList);` throws errors as undefined , I changed it to `widget.saveRiderAndSearchNearRidecallback(widget.rideReqKey,tempList);  still null